# Ionic doesn't go into states with routing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

There is the following index.slim:

```
doctype html
html ng-app="app"
    head lang="en"
        title First phonegap application
        link href="bower_components/ionic/release/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    body
        ion-header-bar
            h1.title
                | Header
        ion-content
            ion-nav-view
        ion-footer-bar
            h1.title
                | Footer
        script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template"
            | 12345
        script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"
        script src="js/main.js"
        script src="cordova.js"
```

And the following main.js:

```
angular.module("app", ["ionic"]).config([
  "$stateProvider", function($stateProvider) {
    return $stateProvider.state("home", {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    });
  }
]).controller("HomeController", [
  "$scope", "$state", function($scope, $state) {
    return console.log(111);
  }
]);
```

When I execute localhost:8888 (I use gulp server) I can see header/footer, but I don't see my home template and console output from controller. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't have a ui-view in your code

Comment: ion-nav-view works in ionic instead of ui-view